# How is (p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬r) ≡ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∧ q)? Is it really distributive property?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The distributive property is very simple and it says **p ∧ ( q ∨ r ) ≡ ( p ∧ q ) ∨ ( p ∧ r )**, but here how is **(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬r) ≡ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∧ q)** which someone told me is according to the distributive property, but I didn't get it.

In simple words, can someone please tell me in parallel & exactly how this proposition **(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬r) ≡ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∧ q)** matches the distributive property **p ∧ ( q ∨ r ) ≡ ( p ∧ q ) ∨ ( p ∧ r )**? What each variable in distributive property means in that proposition. Million Thanks!

Comment: Everyone, note that (if I'm not mistaken) applying the distributive property in the straightforward way to $(p \land q \land \neg r) \lor (p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$ would give you $(p \land \neg r) \land (\neg q \lor q)$, not $(p \land \neg r) \lor (\neg q \land q)$. (The last two operations are different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In
(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ (p ∧ ¬q ∧ ¬r) ≡ (p ∧ ¬r) ∨ (¬q ∧ q),
let
s = p ∧ ¬r.

Then this becomes
(s ∧ q) ∨ (s ∧ ¬q) ≡ s ∨ (¬q ∧ q),
for which the distributive
property is clear.

Of course
you also need the
commutative and associative properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The thing I like in your answer was to suppose, s = p ∧ ¬r which really simplified the problem.

Comment: One conclusion I got from your answer is that we can change the variables (p, q etc) places if there are ∨ , v, biconditional operations in between, except if it is conditional operation. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: You can always rename variables or substitute a variable for an expression as long as the substitution is done everywhere, the variable does not already occur, and the expression is resubstituted eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the theorem:  
|- (p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ p -> p

**___________________________________**

1.(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ p (assumption)
**_________________________**

2.(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r)  (assumption)
3. p     (and eimination)
**_________________________**

**_________________________**

4. p (assumption)
5. p (copy rule)
**_________________________**

6. p  ( ∨e 1, 2-3, 4-5) (or elimination)

**___________________________________**

7. (p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ p -> p

This is how you can prove it.
Also, in my humble opinion, i don't think anything is getting redistributed here, no at least conventionally. It's just a basic tautology/theorem which can be used to simplify the main expression.

Answer (score 0):

Do it step by step, i.e. $(A\land B\land C)\lor(D\land E)\equiv((A\land B\land C)\lor D)\land((A\land B\land C)\lor E)$, etc...

Notice by example that

$$(p\land q\land\lnot r)\lor p\equiv p$$

so the expression simplifies a lot in each step.

Comment: Thanks for this, but dude I'm very confused. how is **(p ∧ q ∧ ¬r) ∨ p ≡ p**? This is not a distributive property. According to which rule. If it was (p v p) ≡  p. I would have considered it a idempotent rule. Please help!

Comment: @GhostRider this is an absorption rule. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsorptionLaw.html) for some basic examples. Notice that if $p\land q\land\lnot r$ is true then $p$ is true obviously because is included in the statement. Then in $(p\land q\land\lnot r)\lor p$ we only need that $p$ is true for the statement be true because $p$ is included in $p\land q\land\lnot r$ i.e. the disjunction is redundant.